# Legend with many elements causes plot to be small

Tags: python, matplotlib

As shown below, not sure whether there are too many signals in one subplot, hence the legend takes too much space, the plot itself is too small, i.e the height is short.

How may I make the plot bigger please?

Code for the plot

```
cm = 1/2.54
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(unique_signals), ncols=1, figsize=(23.5*cm, 17.2*cm))

sig_col = filtered_df.columns[1:]
plot_counter = 0
previous_label = ""
for column in sig_col:
    signal_name = column.split('_')[0] if ':' in column else column[:-1]

    if  signal_name != previous_label or plot_counter == 0:
        ax = axes[plot_counter]
        plot_counter += 1
        ax.grid(True)

    previous_label = signal_name

    ax.plot(filtered_df['time'], filtered_df[column], label=column)

    y_min, y_max = ax.get_ylim()
    more_ext = ['Ilw1_X','Ilw2_X','IvwTrf1_X','IdcP_X','IdcN_X','Vlw2_X', 'Ilw1_Y','Ilw2_Y','IvwTrf1_Y','IdcP_Y','IdcN_Y','Vlw2_Y','Ivlv','IvlvSum','Icir','Ignd']
    percentage = 0.02 if signal_name not in more_ext else 0.2

    y_min_ext = y_min*(1-percentage) if y_min > 0 else y_min*(1+percentage)
    y_max_ext = y_max*(1+percentage) if y_max > 0 else y_max*(1-percentage)
    ax.set_ylim(y_min_ext, y_max_ext)

for ax in axes:
    ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(group_name.split('_')[0]+'.png', dpi=300)
plt.close()
```

[image]

My expectation:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to take a more manual approach to plotting (for better or worse) especially when there are only a few subplots.  For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(23.5*cm, 17.2*cm))
gs0 = fig.add_gridspec(4, 1)  # define number of rows/cols of subplots

# changing "hspace" and "wspace" changes the spacing between subplots...which makes them bigger/smaller within your overall plot
gs0.update(left=0.025, right = 0.975,
           top=0.975, bottom=0.025,
           hspace=0.1, wspace=0.0)

# create subplot axes
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[0])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[2])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[3])

# now plot your data 
for column in sig_col:
    signal_name = column.split('_')[0] if ':' in column else column[:-1]

    if  signal_name != previous_label or plot_counter == 0:
        # NOTE CHANGE HERE
        ax = fig.get_axes()[plot_counter]
        plot_counter += 1
        ax.grid(True)

    # continue with your code
```

This code can be modified for more flexibility (i.e., changing the number of subplots) like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(23.5*cm, 17.2*cm))
gs0 = fig.add_gridspec(len(unique_signals), 1)  # define number of rows/cols of subplots

# changing "hspace" and "wspace" changes the spacing between subplots...which
# makes them bigger/smaller within your overall plot
gs0.update(left=0.025, right = 0.975,
           top=0.975, bottom=0.025,
           hspace=0.1, wspace=0.0)

# now plot your data 
for column in sig_col:
    signal_name = column.split('_')[0] if ':' in column else column[:-1]

    if  signal_name != previous_label or plot_counter == 0:
        # create axis on the fly
        ax = fid.add_subplot(gs0[plot_counter])
        plot_counter += 1
        ax.grid(True)

    # continue with your code


# finally, add your legend(s)
for axis_counter in range(len(unique_signals)):
    ax = fig.get_axes()[axis_counter]
    ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

This approach gives you a lot of control over the individual subplots.  If this does not resolve your issue my next recommendation is to increase the overall figure size, though I suspect you still need to address the inter-subplot spacing (which I do via gridspec).

Comment: so can I make the legend occupy less space as well? for example, a smaller font?

Comment: @Victor Yes, but you really need to make the subplots bigger since you cannot poosibly make the fontsize small enough to resolve this issue and have the legend remain legible.  Look at the documentation (e.g., help(ax.legend)) to see a list of changeable parameters.  Here are the parameters I adjust most often: fontsize, loc, ncol, fancybox, borderpad, labelspacing, borderaxespad, columnspacing.

Comment: thanks, i actually don't know how to adapt your code, as you have a pre-defined number of 4 from gs0 = fig.add_gridspec(4, 1), and then you manually create ax0 to ax3. As you can see from my code, the number for subplot can be different based on len(unique_signals), can I add the hspace and wspace within my code when I am operating at that particular ax?

Comment: @Victor I don't know about your original method (I never do it that way).  I updated my code example to be more flexible on the number of subplots.  Does this make sense?

Comment: it does change the spacing, but how do it add the legend now please? i used to the for loop goes through the axes, but now it is created on the fly, and i can't added the ax.legent() in it, it throws me error, No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument.

Comment: @Victor Ok, I updated the answer to include legends.

Comment: i see, i need to use get_axes(), not familiar, many thanks!!